Less-than / Greater-than Comparisons in Homomorphic Encryption
It seems to be impossible to find a working solution for less-than / greater-than comparison for holomorphic encryption using Microsoft SEAL library, and the library does not seem to provide such functionality. The research papers provide only theoretical approaches without sample codes.
Is there a working example exists anywhere using SEAL library that compares two ciphertexts? that is, produces something as simple as Enc(x1) < Enc(x2) ? true : false.
Related issues on the SEAL library page: #162, #397.
Papers considered:
Ilia Iliashenko and Vincent Zucca, Faster homomorphic comparison operations for BGV and BFV  
Ayantika Chatterjee and Indranil Sengupta, Searching and Sorting of Fully Homomorphic Encrypted Data on Cloud  
Florian Bourse, Olivier Sanders, and Jacques Traore, Improved Secure Integer Comparison via Homomorphic Encryption  
Juan Garay, Berry Schoenmakers, and Jose Villegas, Practical and Secure Solutions for Integer Comparison  

